# Tensorflow older version

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How can I install TensorFlow-gpu 1.0.0 using conda.

I already have Python 3.5 and CUDA 8 but I am not able to find TensorFlow-gpu 1.0.0 with Pip or conda

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install with `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.0.0`. Also, if "pip solution" does not work you can download the wheel from [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.0.0/#files).